# Redirecionar ou negar acesso direto a pasta public

Tags: apache, htaccess, url-rewrite

Estou usando `htaccess` para acessar as pastas `css`, `js`, `images` que estão em `/public` diretamente:

```apacheconf
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Por exemplo, quando acesso está url `http://localhost/css/file.css` ele mostra o conteudo de `http://localhost/public/css/file.css`

Porém eu quero negar acesso se o usuário digitar o "public" no endereço, por exemplo `http://localhost/public/css/file.css`. É possível negar acesso acaso haja o `/public` no endereço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema você pode usar `%{THE_REQUEST}` com `RewriteCond`, examplo:

```apacheconf
RewriteCond "%{THE_REQUEST}" "^GET\s/public/"
```

Se precisar de todos metodos (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc), exemplo de redirecionamento:

```apacheconf
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond "%{THE_REQUEST}" "^[A-Z]+\s/public/"
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ other-directory/$0 [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Nega acesso (será necessário criar um caminho falso):

```apacheconf
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond "%{THE_REQUEST}" "^[A-Z]+\s/public/"
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ fake-directory/$0 [F]

    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que  a diretiva `RewriteBase` é a raíz de `http://localhost/`, adicione a seguinte regra:

```
RewriteRule ^(public/) - [F,L,NC]
```

Essa regra negará acesso a pasta public/.
Caso queira adicionar algum outro path específico, veja um exemplo

```
RewriteRule ^(public/|outrapasta/) - [F,L,NC]
```

Nesse exemplo, está aplicando a regra para public/ e outrapasta/.

Comment: Obrigado Daniel, olhei direito agora, na verdade o problema é outro, quando tento tento acessar `http://localhost/css/file.css` aparece o erro 403 também, o que deveria só aparecer em `http://localhost/public/css/file.css`